# R installation not recognising portuguese characters

Tags: character-encoding

I have been working with R for a long time, and I used portuguese characters without any problem in scripts and even in data files such as .csv. But recently my installation stopped recognising portuguese characters. For example, in the first line of one script I get this:

## Converter de direc��o e intensidade do vento para componentes u,v

## Limpar a mem�ria

rm(list = ls())

I tried

> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Portuguese_Portugal.65001")
> [1] "LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.utf8;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.utf8;LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.utf8"

before reading the script, but it does not work (and even if it did, I would have to repeat this command every time I launch the R console. How can I solve this problem, so that the portuguese characters are recognised in both scripts and text data files? I suspect that I need to change something in my configuration (.Rprofile) but I don´t know how to do it.

Thanks for your attention reading my query.

Carlos M. Lemos

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share `sessionInfo()` and crucial part of your script as well as a data sample  (sanitized if necessary) ad how do you run the script.  Try `CHCP 65001` _before_ running R From an open `cmd` prompt…